# What is the difference between Inheritance and Instantiation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been doing some searching but I don't quite understand the difference between Inheritance and Instantiation.

Both seems the same to me and I can't figure out which to use in what situation.

Comment: Can you please show an example of a situation which confuses you? Or give an explanation of what you believe these terms mean? It's hard to help someone with invisible code.

Comment: They are not comparable in any way! Two different CS terminologies that do different things. 1 or 2 google search(es) should have the answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of objects and classes you can think of it this way.  Lets say you have you created a blueprint of a toy which had two wheels and a handle

```
class Toy
    @wheels
    @handle

    def initialize(wheels, handle)
        @whees = wheels
        @color = handle
    end

    def start
        puts "Vroom"
    end
end
```

Then I see your design and i like it but i want to extend it to include a flashing light.  I could make my own blueprint that was exactly like yours:

```
class FlashyToy
    @whees
    @handle
    @flashyLight
end
```

but that would be a waste so instead I could inherit the wheels and handle from your design and just add the new light:

```
class FlashyToy < Toy
    @flashyLight
end
```

FlashyToy still has wheels and a handle even though I don't explicitly define them because the properties are **Inherited** from the toy class.

Instantiation is where you take make an actual copy the blueprint. So in other words if I make an actual FlashyToy or if I make a Toy then i have instantiated the class

```
toy1 = Toy.new(2, 1)
toy2 = FlashyToy.new(3, 2)
toy1.start  #print Vroom
toy2.start  #print Vroom even though not directly defined in flashy toy
```

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance refers to the way in which classes can import behavior from other classes, e.g.:

```
class Mammal
  def walk
  end
end

class Bat < Mammal
  def fly
  end
end
```

A Bat is a Mammal, but not vice-versa. Given the example above, a Bat can fly *and* walk, but a Mammal can only walk.

Instantatiation refers to the creation of an instance of a Class, e.g.

```
b = Bat.new
```

In the example above `b` is an *instance* of Bat. Instantiated objects can perform any methods defined as instance methods in their class, and can create instance variables to represent state:

```
def set_wing_count
  @wings = 2
end
```

The two concepts are quite different.